# CKEditor images not working

Tags: php, mysql, image, ckeditor

I'm having some trouble with CKEditor.

I have created a blog for my website and a back end section to write new posts and approve comments etc. It's all working fine and I use CKEditor to write and edit posts.

When writing a text only post its fine, it gets stored in the database and subsequently appears on the website as it should. But If I write a post with an image in it it doesnt get stored in the database. All text and images disappear.

The title of the post goes into the database as this is just using a normal text box. But everything in the CKEditor disappears if I put an image in there.

Here are some screen shots:

[image: I press the image button and enter in the explicit URL of the image stored on my server. (http://www.mydomain.com/images/image.jpg)]
I press the image button and enter in the explicit URL of the image stored on my server. (http://www.mydomain.com/images/image.jpg)

[image: When I press ok the image is visible in CKEditor with the text above it.]
When I press ok the image is visible in CKEditor with the text above it.

[image: When I submit the post and then return to it to view or edit it, the CKEditor is empty and only the Title is there. Checking the database I can see the title is entered but the body isnt.]
When I submit the post and then return to it to view or edit it, the CKEditor is empty and only the Title is there. Checking the database I can see the title is entered but the body isnt.

If I dont enter an image everything works fine title and body go into the database and the blog post appears on the site.

Does anyone have any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: Log your `POST` request first to know whether the problem is frontend or backend. If the "body" of your entry is present in `POST`, then something's wrong with your server-side.

Comment: How do you handle the save? It could be a client side issue too if you save via AJAX or something like that? I'm guessing that somewhere between CKE and the DB something is deciding that images are dangerious requests and must be declined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually discovered the answer myself

The image tags created in the CKEditor would be something like

```
<img src="images/picture.jpg">
```

and my SQL query would be something like

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Table (blog_body, blog_title) VALUES ('".$blogBody."','".$blogTitle."')";
```

or something along those lines.

To solve it I just swapped the quotation marks around. Placing the query in single quotes and swapping the quotes about the variables around.

This fixed my problem.

Just thought if someone else is having this trouble this may help

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation for this... It hurts :C