# Images are not showing in CKeditor in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, ckeditor

I currently use Ckeditor as the editor for comments in my WordPress blog.
I downloaded the ckeditor.zip file and uploaded all files onto the root directory of the site after extracting the zip file. And then I hooked it with the comments system by referring to http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation. It works well except a few issues. One of them is that images are not showing.

For example, if I insert an image by clicking "Add an image" button:
[image]

The image is displayed in the comment input box:
[image]

However, when clicking "Post Comment", the image (inserted via image URL) does not appear in actual comments.

I noticed that the image is added in the comment input box in the form of the following in html:

```
<p><img src="http://www.url.com/...../image_name.jpg" /></p>
```

For your reference,

1) I changed the comment_form() part to the following:

```
<?php comment_form(array('comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment">' . 
        '<textarea id="comment" class="ckeditor" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>' .
        '</p>',
    'comment_notes_after' => '')); ?>
```

2) I added the following scripts to the comments.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.url-path.com/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>

                CKEDITOR.replace( 'comment' );
            </script>
```

Anyway to fix this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Note:
I found a similar question ([CKEditor images not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023546/ckeditor-images-not-working)) but I don't know how to reolve this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to run this function on the content posted from CKEditor before inserting into the database,

```
stripslashes($_POST['content']);
```

Comment: Really thanks for your answer. I added an add_filter to hook the comment field with the following code: $comment_field = '<p class="comment-form-comment">' .  '<textarea id="comment" class="ckeditor" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true">' . stripslashes($_POST['comment']) .'</textarea>' . '</p>'; return $comment_field;  However, the problem continues. Any hint to add apply stripslashes() to WordPress comment field? Thanks again.

Comment: Let me make it clear, actually we need to add this stripslashes, before the text gets saved to database,not while displaying the text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to WordPress' settings.
I added tags such as img to kses.php to allow them in WordPress.
Now it works fine.

Thanks.